# Pivot Table in Python with specific arguments

Tags: python, excel, automation, pivot-table

`Filters = Status` & Employee no. `Columns = empty`, `Rows= name`, `values = working` days. I tried using `pandas` but it is giving me dates in different different columns rather than a table. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl
import load_workbook
filename = "TESTINg.xlsx"
workbook = load_workbook(filename)
worksheet_name = "Filters"
worksheet = workbook\\\[worksheet_name\\\]
table_range = worksheet.dimensions
data = worksheet.values
header = next(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
new_worksheet_name = "Pivot Table"
new_worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(title=new_worksheet_name)
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Employee no.' & 'Status',
                             index='name', columns=\\\[\\\],
                             aggfunc='sum', fill_value='')
new_worksheet.append(\\\['Filters:', 'Status', 'Employee no.'\\\])
new_worksheet.append(\\\['Columns:'\\\])
new_worksheet.append(\\\['Rows:', 'name'\\\])
new_worksheet.append(pivot_table.columns.tolis
```

Comment: Please provide TESTINg.xlsx example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.